# code works in visual studio css file, but it's an error in ruby on rails css file

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

code works in visual studio css file, but it's an error in ruby on rails css file

The code below works well in visual studio.

```css
a:visited { 
  color:black; 
}

a{
  text-decoration: none; 
  color: inherit; 
}

ul{
  list-style: none; 
}
```

but but not in ruby on rails. It's marked in red.

[image]

Comment: CSS is CSS. It's fine on whatever surrounding environment. 
Not sure why you have a specific "ruby on rails css" highlighting language interpreter but the difference of color is maybe a convention (I don't know visual studio)

Comment: what's the error? what do you mean with `it's marked in red`?

Comment: Can you look at the image link file?

Answer (score 0):

With your IDE configuration, the theme and colorset; HTML tag CSS's are colored red. nothing to worry about. In CSS there are 3 ways of selecting elements. Id's, classes and tags itself. tags are in red color on your IDE. If it seems like something is working incorrect you can change your colorset.